# Extra properties on forms authentication user profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'd like to use forms authentication for an MVC project but I would also like to associate a few extra properties to the user profile (profile picture, birth date, etc).

Is there a way to simply extend the User object used by forms authentication to store and retrieve these extra properties?

Answer (score 3):

Just have an extra table in your database (say for example `UserDetails`), then you can map the user ID to the membership user table.

You can then add all the additional properties you need on that one. I'd say that was cleaner than hacking away and adding the additional properties onto the actual membership class.